# ASP .NET Filter URL Parameters

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, url, filter, pretty-urls

Can anyone help me filtering URL parameters because I just can't find correct answer for that.

So lets say I have URL like this `Custom/Action/FirstParm/2`

If I have last parameter only 1,2,3 ids in database and I manually enter 10 in URL I want to be redirected somewhere as default. How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with the url filtering, I think you'll end up having to try to load the record from the database and redirect to a page (or show a message on the existing page) indicating that the record does not exist.

```
public ActionResult  Detail(int id) {
  var item = _service.Search(x=>x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
  if (item == null)
    return RedirectToAction("DoesNotExist");

  return View(viewModelWithItem);
}
```